# No option to add stylesheet on PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I've just started to learn Python coding, I'm trying to create a .css file on PyCharm, however when I select File > New I only have 3 options (Python File, Jupyter Notebook and HTML File)

I must be missing something obvious but I just can't see it!

I'm using the latest version of PyCharm

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably linked to your PyCharm edition (Professional and Community Editions).

As you can see from this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), CSS is supported only in Professional Edition. 
So, I suppose that you can't create a .css file for this reason.

Try to update your PyCharm Edition to fix the problem.